# how to fix this combination program using binomial factorial equation?

Tags: python, function, statistics, combinations

my answer for finding the number of combinations given drawing 3 cards out of 52 is off by a spot. Like 0 cards from 52 should = 1, 1 should = 52, 2 = 1326 and so on. but I have 0 = 1, 1 = 1, 2 = 52 and so on. What would I modify to reach the desired result? I think the error is in def factorial() but I can not seem to fix/ find the issue, no matter what I try.

```
def factorial(num):
    i = 2
    if num == 0:
        num = 1
        print(num) 
    elif num > 1:
       for i in range(i, num):
            num = num * i
    return num

def combinations(n,r):
    l = n-r
    nn = factorial(n)
    rn = factorial(r)
    ln = factorial(l)

    result = nn / (rn * ln)

    print(result)
    return result

def main():
    h = 52
    a = 0
    while a<4:
        combinations(h,a)
        a = a + 1
```

Comment: `range(i, num):` -> `range(i, num + 1):` The end argument is excluding.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing extra stuff in factorial which may lead to the confusion. I suggest you print out your final result with comparison to your `a` variable at the end of the `combinations` function like so:

```
print("For a=" + str(r) + ", result=" + str(result))
```

Here is the overall edited code:

```
def factorial(num):
    if num == 0:
        num = 1


    elif num > 1:

       for i in range(2, num):    # Setting i=2 at the start is redundant
            num = num * i
    return num

def combinations(n,r):
    l = n-r

    nn = factorial(n)
    rn = factorial(r)
    ln = factorial(l)

    result = nn / (rn*ln)

    print("For a=" + str(r) + ", result=" + str(result))

    return

h = 52
a = 0

while a<4:
    combinations(h,a)

    a = a + 1
```